# Numpy.where on same column resulting in an empty dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a date stored in a datetime64[ns] variable called "IBKR_cutoff_date".

I also have a dataframe called prev1_contract:

```
         date  Price_PREV_1  OI_PREV_1
0  2021-02-22        523.50      52741
1  2021-02-23        528.75      52383
2  2021-02-24        539.25      52842
3  2021-02-25        541.00      51831
4  2021-02-26        531.00      52839
..        ...           ...        ...
95 2021-07-06        598.75      74271
96 2021-07-07        585.50      57216
97 2021-07-08        592.25      31202
98 2021-07-09        610.00       5071
99 2021-07-12        610.00          0
```

I want to check if dates in column "date" (whose dtype is datetime64[ns]) are greater than IBKR_cutoff_date. If so, dataframe "Price_PREV_1" column must be set as blank (overwriting previous values), otherwise the column's existing value is kept.

I tried:

```
prev1_contract['Price_PREV_1'] = np.where(prev1_contract['date']>IBKR_cutoff_date, '', prev1_contract['Price_PREV_1'] ).astype(float)
```

This results in a strange behaviour:

- if all dates in "date" column are smaller than IBKR_cutoff_date, then the script works fine (previous dates are kept)
- if there is even only one date greater than IBKR_cutoff_date, then the dataframe disappears (if I try to print it or to print its dtypes, nothing comes out as a result).

What am I missing?
Thanks

Comment: What happens if you remove `.astype(float)` from the end?

Comment: Yeah, it should be throwing an error, something along the lines of `ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''`. You should use `np.NaN` to represent missing data in a float column.

Comment: You are right: If I remove .astype(float), it works (oddly, with the previous code I didn't get any error). I added astype(float) because otherwise the column dtype changes from float to object and this created some problems with following operations I need to execute on the df. But I can run pd.to_numeric in a separate line and it works flawlessy. So thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `.astype(float)` from the end of your code, as '' cannot be converted to float